# What is the safest way to check AtomicBoolean and perform something?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

Are any ways to make this operations like one operatinon (kind of custom atomic)?

```
 if (!isShutdownStarted.get()
            && !QUEUE.contains(request.getUserEmail())) {
        try {
            QUEUE.add(request.getUserEmail());
        } 
 //...
 }
```

Code in other thread

```
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    PaymentClient.isShutdownStarted.set(true);
    while (!PaymentClient.QUEUE.isEmpty());
}
```

Comment: write in detail : question description is very short. Write some explanation abt `isShutdownStarted` and `request`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use an `AtomicBoolean` to make another operation or sequence of operations atomic.

If you need to make an intrinsically non-atomic operation or sequence atomic, you need to use locking; e.g. a primitive mutex, a `Lock` or something equivalent.